# What tags cover data dredging?

Tags: discussion, tags

There does not seem to be any one tag covering all of data dredging. The tags I can find are [p-hacking], [stepwise regression], [feature selection] and [model selection].  Are there any other tags that one should look at when looking for Q&As on this topic?

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific `[data-dredging]` tag.  Those tags seem decent.  You could also just search on "dredging" & some synonyms, when looking for relevant threads.

Comment: Another phrase I found useful after posting the q was "post-selection inference". Often that brings up methods to avoid data dredging, but the discussion of dredging in those is useful.

Comment: Depending on the question, [multiple-comparisons] might be OK, possibly [ethics] too (though this one has not a lot of questions yet).